# How to fill area under curve with visual spectrum colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient

I'm trying to create a curve with visual spectrum colors filling the area under the curve.

So the left side of the area under the curve is blue and the right side of the area under the curve is red.

This is an example code:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
x <- seq(-4, 4, length=271)
y <- dnorm(x)

df <- data.frame(x,y)

col <- rainbow(271)

ggplot(data=df) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y = y)) + 
  geom_area(aes(y = y, x = x)) + theme_minimal() + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = '#FF0000FF', high = '#FF0006FF')
```

But all i get is a black area under the curve.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wanted to get a spectrum of visual light colors.

my solution is very similar to the one above. i used `scale_colour_gradientn()`

```
[![library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(colorRamps)

set.seed(1)
x <- seq(-4, 4, length=271)
y <- dnorm(x)

df <- data.frame(x,y)

colfunc<-colorRampPalette(c("royalblue", "green", "springgreen", "yellow2", "yellow", "red", "red2", "red3", "red4"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +  
  geom_segment(aes(xend=x, yend=0, colour=abs(x)^0.7*sign(x)), size = 1) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = colfunc(271))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
df$z  <- sqrt(abs(x))*sign(x)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_area(aes(group=z, color=z)) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = 'blue', high = 'red')
```

***Yielding***

[image: plot]